# XQuery select and check existing employee with message

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, xquery, xquery-sql

i need to output a message saying "matched" or "not an employee" in a column using xquery. I'm using 4444 as a placeholder for now, dont know how to iterate through within the query

```
SELECT
EXTRACTVALUE(B.JOBSHEET_DETAILS, '/jobSheet[@jobNo]/@jobNo') AS "JOB_DETAILS_ID",
XMLQUERY(' for $j in /jobSheet/employee[@empNo]/@empNo
        let $msg := if ($j) then "Employee details match a current employee" else "Error in employee details (no match)"
        where $j = 4444
        return $msg
        '
        PASSING B.JOBSHEET_DETAILS
        RETURNING CONTENT ).getstringval() AS "CHECK_EMP_DETAILS" ,
EXTRACTVALUE(B.JOBSHEET_DETAILS, '/jobSheet/employee[@empNo]/@empNo') AS "EMP_NO",
EXTRACTVALUE(B.JOBSHEET_DETAILS, '/jobSheet/employee/empName') AS "EMP_NAME",
EXTRACTVALUE(B.JOBSHEET_DETAILS, '/jobSheet/dateAttend/date') AS "DATE_ATTENDED"
FROM JOBSHEET_XML_TAB B
where XMLEXISTS('/jobSheet/employee[@empNo]/@empNo' passing B.JOBSHEET_DETAILS);
```

for one, the **else** inside xmlquery doesnt trigger. it outputs (null) when it should be an error.

[image]

I need to check all employees if the $j in this iterations is an existing employee or not. $j = 4444 is it possible to do another select count(*)from emp where no = $num.

Comment: Please show your current and expected output as formatted text, not images; and include the XML that you're trying to get that output from.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to do that in the XPath at all, if it's even possible. You can use [`XMLQuery()` or `XMLTable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB1700) to extract the element and attribute values you're interested in, and then outer-join to the `emp` table to check if they exist, with a case expression to decide what text to display.

Based on what your XML structure appears to be from your current code, something like:

```
select x.job_details_id,
  case when e.no is not null then 'Employee details match a current employee'
    else 'Error in employee details (no match)' end as check_emp_details,
  x.emp_no,
  x.emp_name,
  x.date_attended
from jobsheet_xml_tab jxt
cross join XMLTable(
  '/jobSheet/employee[@empNo]'
  passing jxt.jobsheet_details
  columns job_details_id number path './../@jobNo',
    emp_no number path './@empNo',
    emp_name varchar2(20) path './empName',
    date_attended date path './../dateAttend/date'
) x
left join emp e on e.no = x.emp_no;
```

Quick demo with made-up XML and `emp` record in CTEs:

```
with jobsheet_xml_tab(jobsheet_details) as (
  select xmltype('<jobSheet jobNo="666666">
 <dateAttend>
  <date>2017-05-01</date>
 </dateAttend>
 <employee empNo="7777">
  <empName>Joe</empName>
 </employee>
</jobSheet>') from dual
  union all
  select xmltype('<jobSheet jobNo="777777">
 <dateAttend>
  <date>2017-05-03</date>
 </dateAttend>
 <employee empNo="4444">
  <empName>Jane</empName>
 </employee>
</jobSheet>') from dual
),
emp (no) as (
  select 4444 from dual
)
select x.job_details_id,
  case when e.no is not null then 'Employee details match a current employee'
    else 'Error in employee details (no match)' end as check_emp_details,
  x.emp_no,
  x.emp_name,
  x.date_attended
from jobsheet_xml_tab jxt
cross join XMLTable(
  '/jobSheet/employee[@empNo]'
  passing jxt.jobsheet_details
  columns job_details_id number path './../@jobNo',
    emp_no number path './@empNo',
    emp_name varchar2(20) path './empName',
    date_attended date path './../dateAttend/date'
) x
left join emp e on e.no = x.emp_no;

JOB_DETAILS_ID CHECK_EMP_DETAILS                             EMP_NO EMP_NAME             DATE_ATTE
-------------- ----------------------------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------
        666666 Error in employee details (no match)            7777 Joe                  01-MAY-17
        777777 Employee details match a current employee       4444 Jane                 03-MAY-17
```

It probably isn't useful, but in principle this would cope with a job that had multiple employees assigned to it, which using the deprecated `extractvalue()` could not.